# Keep getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to make functionality for adding friends. This snippet handles it.

```
Router.route("/confirm_friend").post(function(req, res) {
  UserSchema.findOne({ _id: req.body.self }).then(
    (self) => {
      UserSchema.findOne({ _id: req.body.whom }).then(
        (whom) => {
          self.friends.push(whom)
          whom.friends.push(self);
          self.requests.splice(self.requests.indexOf(whom), 1);
          self.save();
          whom.save();
          res.send("success");
        },
        (err) => {
          res.send(err);
          console.log("--- err", err);
        },
      );
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log("--- err", err);
    },
  );
});
```

As you can I am receiving via **POST** two IDs. I am looking for them in Schema, then push each other to the friends lists. After this I do `.save()` and `res.send("success");`
Everything seems OK, but I keep getting in console this :

/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongo*ose/lib/utils.js:249
function cloneObject(obj, options) {
                    ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at cloneObject (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:249:21)
    at clone (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:183:16)
    at cloneObject (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:257:11)
    at clone (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:183:16)
    at cloneObject (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:257:11)
    at clone (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:183:16)
    at cloneObject (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:257:11)
    at clone (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:183:16)
    at cloneObject (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:257:11)
    at clone (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:183:16)
    at cloneObject (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:257:11)
    at clone (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:183:16)
    at cloneObject (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:257:11)
    at clone (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:183:16)
    at cloneObject (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:257:11)
    at clone (/Users/shchypylov/Documents/projects/personal/social/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:183:16)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...*

How may I fix it?

Comment: Usually this sign circular references issue (one object references other and vice versa)..

Comment: If I would guess, it causes `self.friends.push(whom)` and `whom.friends.push(self)`. This is circular reference.

Comment: @bigless hm.. so I how would you implement adding friends to each others lists?

Comment: I am not familiar with no-sql dbs but i think that it should be referenced via object _id and it is googable question